# private setter for a list of custom object

Tags: c#, properties, private, public, getter-setter

I have this code which works fine

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private static ObservableCollection<Archive> _archiveList = new ObservableCollection<Archive>();
    public static ObservableCollection<Archive> archiveList { get { return _archiveList; } }
}
private void build_archiveList()
{
    // create new Archive
    // add the new Archive to archiveList
}
```

...but if I try to use auto implemented properties it just won't work and I don't understand why.
Code with auto implemented properties:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public static ObservableCollection<Archive> archiveList { get; private set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
            InitializeComponent();

            archiveList = new ObservableCollection<Archive>();
            build_archiveList();
    }
}
```

Why doesn't the second approach work?

EDIT: sorry for being incomplete, the list has binding with a datagrid and the datagrid remains empty when using the second approach (altough the new archive is added since archiveList.count is increased with both approaches)

how build_archiveList adds an archive to the list (observablecollection):

```
tmpArchive.content.Add(new ArchiveFile(bfile.FileName, bfile.Crc.ToString(), false));
archiveList.Add(tmpArchive);
```

Comment: What exactly won't work? Show implementation of `build_archiveList()`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, I made an edit to my original post. The build_archiveList is 30-40 lines, should i post it here full?

Comment: In the first version, your property is static, in the second, it's instance. What about the method, is it static or not? Is it intentional?

Comment: oops, that's a typo. it should be static in both examples

Comment: Is there any specific reason behind making this property static?

Comment: I'm discussing if it should be static here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504432/static-vs-instance-members-in-mainwindow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move

```
archiveList = new ObservableCollection<Archive>();
```

to the static constructor.

**Explanation**

You bind to auto property (binding occurs in `InitializeComponent`)which is null, then you add new list.

Comment: what do you mean? that's what I did in the second example, isn't it (since it insn't possible to combine auto implemented properties and initialization)?

Comment: Once again: Move the initialization of the static property to the **static constructor**. Keyword is **static**.

Comment: ah thanks a lot! I now understand why it doesn't work! so actually I should initialize archiveList before InitializeComponent is called if I want to use the auto implemented properties? (writing it on the same line as declaration of archiveList is impossible so I will write it on a line just above InitializeComponent, that's good, right?)

Comment: Why to add before `InitializeComponent`? You must read about [Static Constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx).

Comment: Do you mean I should write a "static MainWindow()" with the inialization of archiveList in it?
btw what i said in my last comment works, is it a bad way to do it?

Comment: Best practice to initialize static members in static constructor.